# How to develop a "Check All" feature on a large, paginated grid/table

Tags: datagrid, pagination, kendo-grid, selectall

I am looking for advice on best practices regarding the following scenario.

I have a grid that supports server-side pagination.

Let's say that there are 100,000 records in the grid, and each page size is 100 records.

Let's say they "Select All".

Considering the records are paginated, do you store a list of "selected" records client-side or server-side?

My first pass was to have the service page that populates the grid to return a comma delimited list of all the records primary keys for future reference alongside the normal dataset, but this seems clunky or even dangerous with large datasets.

My second pass was to store all the records in a special table for future reference, but this adds a lot of overhead in the form of table management to the process.

Or something else? Thanks!

Comment: "Select All" thing is in header of grid or manual selection of each row ?

Comment: You should rethink your process. Maybe an additional button "Do stuff with all records" would be the better idea. You won't have fun creating an array with 100,000 records, nor do you want to submit this array. Both things would take way too long.

Comment: @AGH The "Select All" option is in the header of the grid, and supplements the manual selection of each row.

Comment: @CarstenFranke You may be right. There is, in fact, only 1 thing they can do with the checked entries (move them to another bucket). I could easily make this a function that effectively gets the same result set and subsequent SQL insert into the other table. Thanks for the thought.